# How to run software updater once a day only?

Tags: 22.04, update-manager, update-notifier

It seems to me that software updater is running several times a day (Ubuntu 22.04).

This consumes CPU and network resources, possibly at times when they are needed for more important things.

The run setting is set to Daily.  It should only run once a day.

How to make this happen?

Edit:

**This question is not about managing the time of the day that software updater runs.**

It is about seeing several messages during the day saying "your system is up to date", which I interpreted as software updater running many times a day.

I have gone and looked at the system logs for the past few days, and it seems that software updater is actually only running once a day.

But what seems to be running several times a day is this apt news service.

So does this service generate such a message for the user when done?

Edit 2:

Another possibility is that this is something to do with the ESM cache update service.

See below the log entry runs for update-notifier over the past days:

[image: update-notifier/package-system-locked]

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that updates run several times a day, for some unclear reason, not necessarily just now the time of the day that they run.

Comment: @popey I fail to see why this should be a duplicate for the following reasons: a.The linked question does not provide an answer for a currently supported Ubuntu version b. The described question does not seem to be the same (frequency per day vs time of day).

Comment: The question seems similar enough to me to be considered a duplicate. That the linked duplicate has no answer is irrelevant -- it's still the same question. Frequency per day vs time of day seems liek splitting hairs because both are handled by the same timer.

Comment: Now the duplicate has a relevant answer to this question.